# Unable to save null to ForeignKey in an intermediate model - Django

Tags: python, django

My use case is, there is a **Workshop** and there are multiple positions (**Workshop_Position**) in it. For any position there will be multiple applications. The workshop owner has to approve an application for the user to be a *team_member* in the workshop.

I am using a ManyToMany relationship for this, see below my models.

```
class Workshop(models.Model):
    ...
    team_members = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,  related_name='member_in_workshops', through='Membership')
   ...

class Workshop_Position(models.Model):
    position_heading = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    ...

class Membership(models.Model): 
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='membership', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    position = models.ForeignKey('Workshop_Position', related_name='membership', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    workshop = models.ForeignKey('Workshop', related_name='membership', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
       unique_together = ("position", "user")
```

So when a new position is created, I am saving the position to the **Workshop_Position** table and attempting to save the workshop the position belongs to with a *null* user into the **Membership**. I need to save this with a null user because there are going to be multiple applications to a Workshop_Position and the owner selects which user gets into the position. I am doing the below,

```
{
    "user": " ",
    "position": "3",
    "workshop": "1"
}
```

Please find below my MembershipSerializer

```
class MembershipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset = UserProfile.objects.all(), allow_null=True)
    position = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset = Workshop_Position.objects.all())
    workshop = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset = Workshop.objects.all())

    class Meta:        
        model = Membership
        extra_kwargs = {
            'user': {'required': False, 'allow_null': True}
        }
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'position', 'workshop', 'date_joined')
```

But I get an error when I try to save the above to the **Membership** model.

> "user": [ "This field may not be null." ]

Why do I get this error? I have provided the user within Membership model to have *blank=True, null=True*

Can someone please help me with this.

Thanks!

Comment: remove `user` from your json payload :)

Comment: also, `position` and `workshop` values should be ***`integer`***, not ***string of integer***

Comment: Thanks @JPG, I tried

{
    "position": 3,
    "workshop": 1
}

and I get the error

"user": [
        "This field is required."
    ]

Comment: can you add the serializer?

Comment: I've added my serializer @JPG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using DRF ModelSerializer? In that case you'll need to declare this in your Serializer Class Meta.

```
class MembershipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Membership
        extra_kwargs = {
            'user': {'required': False, 'allow_null': True}   # the allow_null might not be needed
        }
```

**EDIT**

I checked the DRF docs for [PrimaryKeyRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield). As you can see there is something like this.

```
allow_null - If set to True, the field will accept values of None or the empty string for nullable relationships. Defaults to False.
```

So you'd need to change all your `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` like this.

```
serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=your_queryset, allow_null=True)
```

Comment: Yes, I am using DRF Serializer,

I am editing my original post with my serializer with the changes you suggedted. 
I still get the error "user": [ "This field is required." ]  though. Is this because I have user as a PrimaryKeyRelatedField?

Comment: The allow_null in extra_kwargs might throw an error. Do check for it.

Comment: I still get an error "user": [ "This field is required." ] after adding allow_null=True to the PrimaryKeyRelatedField, I'm updating my serializer in the post

Comment: ok so if I send this payload, it accepts it!

{
    "user": null,
    "position": 3,
    "workshop": 1
}